# Concerning the reason for using componentDidMount vs componentWillMount for API calls

Tags: reactjs

I was learning React and wanted to use AJAX to send requests to API. Then, after the research done, I found out that we have componentWillMount and componentDidMount. Initially, the former one seemed appealing but later found out that componentDidMount is the best choice because in this hook when we update the state with setState component gets rerendered but IT IS NOT the case with componentWillMount in which even if we update the state with setState component DOES NOT get rerendered. The question is "Are these statements true?"

Comment: While it's true you can update the state without re-rendering in `componentWillMount`, this won't apply to you since you're doing an asynchronous AJAX request.

Comment: and ```componentWillMount``` is deprecated.

Comment: @Jayce444, that is, setting the state in componentWillMount will not make a component rerender but will in componentDidMount. Right?

Comment: ```componentWillMount ``` is called before the component mounts, it will not cause re-rendering.

Comment: Don't use componentWillMount, it's deprecated.